# Insights in a more complex multilevel model

Tags: mixed-model, references

I'm looking to understand how to build a multilevel model using Stan.
The structure I'm looking at is `y ~ x + (x|z) + (x|w)`

By following the "Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models" I can see that for  `y ~ x + (x|z)` the model should look like
[image]

There are examples ([link](https://willhipson.netlify.app/post/stan-random-slopes/varying_effects_stan/)) that show how the  `y ~ x + (x|z)` can be in Stan but I cannot find an example about the

`y ~ x + (x|z) + (x|w)` (in Stan or in general the mathematical form of it).
Is there any book, paper or something that goes though the case I'm looking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just add another more random term.

But it might be useful to move the fixed effect $\mu_\alpha$ and $\mu_\beta$ outside of the equation for the random effect. As you can add multiple random terms but not multiple fixed effects.

So use

$$y_i \sim N(\overbrace{\mu_\alpha + \mu_\beta x_i}^{1+x} + \overbrace{ \alpha_{j[i]}+ \beta_{j[i]} x_i}^{(1+x|j)}, \sigma_y^2), \\ 
\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_j \\ \beta_j \end{pmatrix} \sim N \left( \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} \sigma_\alpha^2 & \rho \sigma_\alpha \sigma_\beta \\ \rho \sigma_\alpha \sigma_\beta &  \sigma_\beta^2  \end{pmatrix}   \right)$$

and add another term

$$y_i \sim N(\overbrace{\mu_\alpha + \mu_\beta x_i}^{1+x} +\overbrace{ \alpha_{j[i]}+ \beta_{j[i]} x_i}^{(1+x|j)} + \overbrace{\alpha'_{j[k]}+ \beta'_{j[k]} x_i}^{(1+x|k)}, \sigma_y^2), \\ 
\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_j \\ \beta_j \end{pmatrix} \sim N \left( \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} \sigma_\alpha^2 & \rho \sigma_\alpha \sigma_\beta \\ \rho \sigma_\alpha \sigma_\beta &  \sigma_\beta^2  \end{pmatrix}   \right)
\\ 
\begin{pmatrix} \alpha'_j \\ \beta'_j \end{pmatrix} \sim N \left( \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} {\sigma'}_\alpha^2 & \rho' {\sigma'}_\alpha {\sigma'}_\beta \\ \rho' {\sigma'}_\alpha {\sigma'}_\beta &  {\sigma'}_\beta^2  \end{pmatrix}   \right)$$

---

In the above I write the random effects as $(1+x|j)$ and $(1+x|k)$.

- I took over the notation from your image, but you can replace $j[i]=z_i$ and $j[k] = w_i$, and the $\alpha_{z_i},\beta_{z_i}$ are the first random intercept and random slopes terms, and $\alpha'_{w_i},\beta'_{w_i}$ are the second.
- I use $(1+x|j)$ instead of $(x|j)$ to make it more explicit that the intercept term is also included.

Comment: So if I got this right, the a_k and b_k are the varying slopes and intercepts for the (x|w) part?